# Curious problem using VirtualDub

Tags: encoding, performance, video-editing, virtualdub

I have a simple video which i've cropped and trimmed down in VirtualDub. I've then re-saved it as AVI; however the video now plays very slowly/cchoppily in Windows Media Player. Is there any particular reason for this?

Comment: What were the audio and video codec settings? Copy/copy? What shows up in File->Properties for the new file vs. the old?

Comment: Video was set to Full Processing mode and audio was set to Direct Stream Copy. As far as info on the files, the only thing that looks odd is that the output has a lower bitrate, but everything else looks fine. And if it matters, the video was originally recorded with FRAPS.

Comment: did you try in another media player like VLC?  since VLC uses a completely separate rendering system it's good for troubleshooting encoding issues: if WMP doesn't play back right, compare VLC's playback to see if the problem is in the file or in the codec.

Comment: Downloading vlc now... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a quirk of WMP that causes this. It plays in VLC just fine...